# How to configure baud rate of a serial port (/dev/ttySx)

Tags: linux, kernel, uart

I created a new kernel module to setup a network device, using a board connected to the Linux platform with a serial port. (/dev/ttySx)
This module is similar to the SLIP module. It defines a new line discipline.

Everything works fine, except the baud rate configuration.
The board I'm using needs a specific baud rate during configuration and after a new baudrate for data transfer.

I tried to configure this baud rate with the tty_encode_baud_rate() primitive and I can see, using the tty_termios_baud_rate() primitive, that it is correctly set. The problem is that it doesn't work. The UART baud rate is not changed.

I need help on this point.

The source code I used to change the baudrate is:

```
down_write( &tty->termios_rwsem);
old_termios = tty->termios;
cflag = tty->termios.c_cflag;
tty_encode_baud_rate(tty, (speed_t)115200, (speed_t)115200);
if (tty->ops->set_termios)
    tty->ops->set_termios(tty, &old_termios);
printk( " New TTY baudrate is %d\n", tty_termios_baud_rate(&tty->termios));
up_write(&tty->termios_rwsem);
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it with this code snippet in my ldisc open function:

```
struct ktermios new_termios;
/* set baudrate */
down_read(&tty->termios_rwsem);
new_termios = tty->termios;
up_read(&tty->termios_rwsem);
tty_termios_encode_baud_rate(&new_termios, 38400, 38400);
tty_set_termios(tty, &new_termios);
```